# Find installed dictionary

Tags: 11.04, repository, search

I installed dict-freedict english-french from Ubuntu Software Center. Synaptic Package Manager shows it installed in Section: Word Processing (universe) but I cannot locate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In synaptic, you can select an installed package, right click, and select 'Properties'. There should be a tab named 'Files' that lists out all of the files contained in the package. This should tell you where your files were installed too.

Comment: Thank you Gus. I don't understand where it is. Under 'Common' it shows Section: Word Processing (universe). Here is the last line of the 'Installed Files': /usr/share/opendict/dictionaries/plain/freedict-fra-eng.dict.dz/file/freedict-fra-eng.index  In the future, is there a way to specify where I want the software or to add a launcher?

Comment: Not that I know of. All the packages in the repo that include GUI executables will have the launchers created for you. (They have to pass through the code reviews, and they typically don't approve packages that aren't properly packaged.) In this case, I believe that you don't have a launcher because this package is not an actual application, just a set of database files.

Comment: I had to add the dict protocol and now it works fine. Thanks  sudo apt-get install dictd
sudo apt-get install dict-gcide
sudo apt-get install dict-moby-thesaurus

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are are looking for the application. But dict-freedict english-french is only the database. You need an application to use that database

check my previous post here: [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57143/koreanenglish-dictionary-app/57148#57148)

That is for Korean->English. Similarly you can check the English-french.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the database. Now you have to install the software. An option would be [OpenDict](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/opendict).